# React Native Expo iOS Use Strong Password feature not working

Tags: ios, react-native, passwords, expo

- SDK Version: 42.0.1
- Platforms: iOS (v. 14.7.1)
- Device : iPhone 12 pro max ;

Hi everyone ! After several attempts to integrate the autofill iOS’s functionality with the prop newPassword of TextInput component, I finally decided to ask help.

I have a simple registration form with three fields:

- username
- password
- password verification

Here is the simplest code which is supposed to work but which does not :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textContentType="username"
        placeholder="username"
    />
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="password"
        textContentType="newPassword"
    />
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="confirm password"
        textContentType="newPassword"
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit} >
        <Text>
            submit
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Expected behavior :

I would like the password autofill feature to fire at the focus of one of the two inputs that have the newPassword property like this :

[image]
In fact, the above screenshot comes from the application running under Expo and the feature works fine.

I specify that when I touch the input username, auto fill password only works on the first input password like this:

[image]

Okay, now when I build my app to test it **via TestFligth, these features don’t work at all**. I know there is some configurations to set up :

My phone’s keychain is active.

AutoFill Credential Provider is active on App ID Configuration

Here is my app.json iOS configuration :

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myIdentifier.identifier",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.4",
      "associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:www.mywebsite.com",
        "webcredentials:www.mywebsite.com"
      ],
      "entitlements": {
        "com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info": "true"
      },
    },
```

I can’t seem to find where something is missing ! Maybe in the app.json ?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm in the same boat

Comment: Sadly, i never did

Comment: I am facing the same error, and not solution found yet.